# How to get the scroll ranges of an NSScrollView via the accessibility interface?

Tags: cocoa, accessibility

I'm trying to get all possible information from an NSScrollView using the accessibility interface in Cocoa. I can read various things like the id, enabled state, scroll position, frame etc. by I can't for the life of me find a way to get current client area (= the size of the document view). It would be simple if I could get the scroll ranges of the 2 scrollbars, but also that seems impossible. Does anyone have a solution for this problem and can share it here? Or at least can provide an idea?

Here's a list of the accessibility properties for a scrollbar:

```
<AXApplication: “gui-test”>
 <AXWindow: “GUI Test App”>
  <AXTabGroup>
   <AXSplitGroup>
    <AXGroup>
     <AXScrollArea>
      <AXScrollBar>

Attributes:
   AXEnabled:  “1”
   AXOrientation:  “AXHorizontalOrientation”
   AXParent:  “<AXScrollArea>”
   AXChildren:  “<array of size 5>”
   AXFocused:  “0”
   AXSize:  “w=261 h=16”
   AXRole:  “AXScrollBar”
   AXTopLevelUIElement:  “<AXWindow: “GUI Test App”>”
   AXHelp:  “(null)”
   AXChildrenInNavigationOrder:  “<array of size 5>”
   AXPosition:  “x=598 y=494.5”
   AXWindow:  “<AXWindow: “GUI Test App”>”
   AXRoleDescription:  “scroll bar”
   AXValue (W):  “1”
   AXHidden (W):  “1”
   AXFrame:  “x=598 y=494.5 w=261 h=16”
   AXIdentifier:  “_NS:448”
```

I also tried to set a very high value (= scroll position), to read what the maximum accepted scroll position is, but that value only works in the range [0..1] (i.e. percent). So this a dead end as well.

Then I tried to find a relation between the scroll range and the scroll thumb size, which works somewhat, but only for not so big scroll areas. And it stops working entirely when the scroll thumb width (for the horizontal scrollbar) reaches a certain value (for me 26px). It doesn't get smaller than that. What else could I try?

**Update**:

I found this comment in `AXAttributeConstants.h`:

```
/*!
    @define kAXMinValueAttribute

    Only used in conjunction with kAXValueAttribute and kAXMaxValueAttribute, this
    attribute represents the minimum value that an element can display. This is useful
    for things like sliders and scroll bars, where the user needs to have an understanding
    of how much the kAXValueAttribute can vary.

    Value: Same data type as the element's kAXValueAttribute.

    Writable? No.

    Required for many user maniipulatable elements. See kAXValueAttribute for more
    details.
*/
```

which seems to indicate there must be a min + max value for scrollbars. Yet I only get an error when I try to read any of them.

Comment: Did you try `kAXMaxValueAttribute` and `kAXMinValueAttribute`? "The minimum value this accessibility object can display (for example, the minimum value of a scroller control).".

Comment: Unfortunately these attributes are neither supported on the scrollbar nor the value indicator.

Comment: The min and max of the scroll bar are 0.0 and 1.0, not very usefull. Can't you get the document view of the scroll view?

Comment: The document view is not listed in the accessibility hierarchy. Scrollbars and content are direct children of the scroll area. I'm thinking of a hack however, like take any child of the scroll area and scroll the box one page left (after having set the horz scroll offset to 0), which is a supported action. Determine original and scrolled bounds to find the size of one page, which should correspond to the scroll area's width, and compute the total width. But that's ugly.

Comment: How do you access AXChildrenInNavigationOrder ? Apple does not seem to have constant for it

Comment: You mean how I could list the value above? This is from the (old) accessibility demo app and there are no constants used. Instead a list of available properties is queried and then the demo iterates over that list and queries the indvidual values.